# Not able to make a successful POST request

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, http-post

I am trying to make a post request, but overtime I am getting error (coded in HTML). Here's my code:

```
    if([mode isEqualToString:@"online"])
        {
            NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://130.1.5.183:9999/visit-reporting/content/visitreportservice/getCoverInfo"];
        
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
            request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        
            NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"gds68342jhgdfk279364jkdbgfjksd82347", @"53afs", @"abc@def.com", @"2009-06-15T13:45:30", @"iPad", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"responseToken",@"userId", @"email", @"timeStamp", @"userAgent", nil]];
            NSString *requestBodyData = [jsonDictionary description];
        
            NSData *bodyData = [requestBodyData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            request.HTTPBody = bodyData;
            
            @try {
                NSOperationQueue *q = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:q completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                    
                    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                    NSMutableDictionary *parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&connectionError];
                    
                    if(!parsedData)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Not able to parse data");
                    }
                    else
                    {
// DO something
                       }
                }];
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [exception description]);
            }
            @finally {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //get cover information from offline database
        }
```

However, when checking the response using a REST client (named COCOA REST CLIENT), the desired response is shown. Where is the issue?

This is the response I am getting when sending POST request from my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>An error has occured</p>
    
    <p>Click <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">here</a> to navigate back to the page you were on previously.</p>
    
    
        <p>If this problem persists, please contact <a href="mailto:Support.vwg@vwg.co.uk?Subject=Visit Reporting Error&Body=Hi,%0D%0A%0D%0AI have been experiencing problems with the Visit Reporting application.%0D%0A%0D%0ACould you please look into this issue?">Support.vwg@vwg.co.uk</a></p>
    
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work as you expected:

> ```
> NSString *requestBodyData = [jsonDictionary description];
> ```

You need to use `NSJSONSerialization`'s class method

`dataWithJSONObject:options:error:`

in order to get a `NSData`object containing a sequence of UTF-8 characters from your `NSDictionary` object.

See also: [NSJSONSerialization Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/dataWithJSONObject:options:error:)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I see is that you are using POST request and posting data but aren't setting @"Content-Length"

so add:

```
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[bodyData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

before running connection